# PHP $_SESSION doesn't work in facebook canvas app with only Internet Explorer

Tags: php, session, facebook-apps

I am developing a facebook app which you can find at this URL:
https://www.facebook.com/beratuslufan/app_685231404880763

I almost completed the development but. Every browsers but with Internet Explorer $_SESSION functionality doenst work with facebook app.  Currently, in the app I'am directly redirecting user to setsession.php and then when you go to getsession.php it says "Undefined index: variable_in_session in /home/beratuslu.com/httpdocs/fb/apps/resim-yarismasi/getsession.php on line 3"

interestingly, if you visit source of app which is http://www.beratuslu.com/fb/apps/resim-yarismasi/setsession.php it works. and app suddenly starting to work properly.

How can i overcome on this problem? 
Any helps appreciated..

Comment: your app is not live, so we cannot see it. and your code is not visible for us either. not much we can do with that information.

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: your right now I set it to Public. I am testing it with ie 11 but i think all versions same problem.

Comment: At least you can show me a path how can i track the problem.